# How do I get WPF to choose my 16x16-pixel icon instead of down-scaling a larger one?

Tags: wpf, ico

For a WPF appplication, using either Greenfish or IcoFX, I create a .ico with 16x16 and 64x64 images. I made several versions of the 16x16 one for every available bit depth/number of colors, but it always scales down the 64x64 version to 16x16 on a window's title bar. How do I get it to choose my 16x16 versions rather than down-scaling the 64x64 one? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the relevant XAML?

Comment: There's neither code nor XAML involved. I just create a .ico file and assign it as the application icon through the project properties and as the Window icon for any Windows. It never shows the 16x16 version, only the 32x32 version scaled down to 16x16,